# Prove that they are equivalent

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

> Given two real numbers $(a_k)^n_1$ and $(b_k)_1^n$, prove that
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i \le \sum_{i=1}^n b_ix_i \text{ for any } x_1 \le
>  x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n$$ is equivalent to $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i =
>  \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^k b_i
> \text{, for }k=1,2,\cdots ,n-1$$

The solution states this way :

> Abel sum; taking $\Delta_k \equiv 0, x_n = 1$, we get the equality of full sums. For $x_n = 0, \Delta_k = \delta_k$, we get the rest of it. For the converse, it simply plugs into the Abel sum.

I don't understand the solution, since I don't know what the symbols mean right there, but I get it for the converse. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, plug in $x_{1}=...=x_{n}=1$ to get $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\le\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}$, then plug $x_{1}=...=x_{n}=-1$ to get $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\ge\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}$, hence these sum are equal. Then plug in $x_{1}=...=x_{k}=0,x_{k+1}=...=x_{n}=1$ to get $\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}a_{i}\le\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}b_{i}$ but since we know the total sum are equal, subtracting from that give us $\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}\ge\sum_{i=1}^{k}b_{i}$. This is the answer given in the book, the claim $\Delta_{k}=0$ mean there are no consecutive differences between the any of the $x_{i}$, which is equivalent to saying that they are all equal. The claim $\Delta_{k}=\delta_{k}$ mean that $x_{k}=x_{k+1}-1$ but beside that exception there are no differences between consecutive number.

Since you said you already got the converse this will be omitted, but it's also directly plug and chug.